# Issue to send data to server via Web Service

Tags: c++, web-services, soap, mfc, asmx

I have some issue where I wanted to send this information via web service. My program is using MFC 6.0. There are several other functions besides this UploadStripMapping and other functions works well. Somehow, I have some issue here where this data is not captured in the server's log. But, if I send data with wrong XML format, then the server will reply with format error.

Below is the statement that I wanted to send over:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">                        <soap12:Body>                          <UploadStripMapping xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">                               <strXML><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                   
<root>                 
<info>                 
    <StripID>1234ABDD</StripID>                
    <LotID>B Version</LotID>                   
    <Rows>18</Rows>                
    <Columns>48</Columns>                  
    <Panels>4</Panels>                 
    <MachineID>3RD019</MachineID>                  
    <DateCreated>2016-07-04 13:27:43</DateCreated>                 
</info>
<Mapping>
    <Col1>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col1>
    <Col2>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col2>
    <Col3>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col3>
    <Col4>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col4>
    <Col5>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col5>
    <Col6>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col6>
    <Col7>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col7>
    <Col8>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col8>
    <Col9>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col9>
    <Col10>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col10>
    <Col11>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col11>
    <Col12>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col12>
    <Col13>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col13>
    <Col14>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col14>
    <Col15>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col15>
    <Col16>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col16>
    <Col17>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col17>
    <Col18>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col18>
    <Col19>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col19>
    <Col20>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col20>
    <Col21>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col21>
    <Col22>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col22>
    <Col23>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col23>
    <Col24>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col24>
    <Col25>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col25>
    <Col26>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col26>
    <Col27>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col27>
    <Col28>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col28>
    <Col29>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col29>
    <Col30>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col30>
    <Col31>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col31>
    <Col32>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col32>
    <Col33>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col33>
    <Col34>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col34>
    <Col35>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col35>
    <Col36>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col36>
    <Col37>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col37>
    <Col38>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col38>
    <Col39>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col39>
    <Col40>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col40>
    <Col41>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col41>
    <Col42>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col42>
    <Col43>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col43>
    <Col44>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col44>
    <Col45>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col45>
    <Col46>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col46>
    <Col47>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col47>
    <Col48>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</Col48>
</Mapping>
</root></strXML>                           </UploadStripMapping>                        </soap12:Body>                  </soap12:Envelope>
```

Here's how I write the send statement in my program, the data above I set as strXML:

```
HTTPMethod = _bstr_t( "POST" );
httpReq->open(HTTPMethod, HTTPUrl, _variant_t(VARIANT_FALSE), _variant_t(), _variant_t());  
httpReq->setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml");

szRequest.Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?> \ <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"  xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\"> \
                        <soap12:Body>\
                           <UploadStripMapping xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"> \
                              <strXML>\ %s \ </strXML>\
                           </UploadStripMapping>\
                        </soap12:Body>\
                    </soap12:Envelope>", strXML);

vRequest.vt = VT_BSTR;
vRequest.bstrVal = szRequest.AllocSysString();

httpReq->send(vRequest);
bsResponse = httpReq->responseText;
```

Can anyone give some advice or point out my mistake in this code? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If you end up figuring this out, would you also mind submitting this to http://thedailywtf.com?

Comment: You have a stray `XML` header (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`) in the body of your `XML` - is that intended?.

Comment: The server will reply format error if I don't include the XML header. Originally, I left out the header.

Comment: Like Galik says I think the second xml header is wrong.